How Can I Mock Asynchronous Microservices?
I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I want to build a mock server to handle communication between some microservices. There are both synchronous and asynchronous communications between them, and the concern is that we expect new microservices to be added in the future. The mock server should be able to automatically handle these new services as well.
I've considered solutions like implementing contract testing with mock servers, but that only works with HTTP API communication. Our system also includes service queues and buses, which complicates things. The goal is to make development easier by allowing developers to run only the microservice they are working on. By mocking the other services, especially those from other teams that the service needs to communicate with, we can avoid the overhead of running all the services.

"I've considered solutions like implementing contract testing with mock servers, but that only works with HTTP API communication" - why do you think you can't do this for non-HTTP services?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
